# ¿Cómo detectar correctamente los lados de cada polígono en una imagen?

Tags: python, imagen, objeto, opencv, rectangle

Tengo el siguiente código que me permite **identificar** todos los objetos/**polígonos** en una imagen y estoy intentando **obtener los lados** de cada polígono pero en la mayoría de cuadrados me da que tienen más de 4 lados, supongo que será por la mala resolución y por pequeños píxeles.

Creo que el código está bien porque hay figuras que me las detecta correctamente y, además, he estado siguiendo un tutorial en [este enlace](https://omes-va.com/detectando-figuras-geometricas-con-opencv-python/). No sé mucho sobre opencv pero lo único que se me ocurre es **reducir el ruido** de la imagen o aplicar un poco de **tolerancia** para ignorar aquellos lados menores de cierta cantidad de píxeles --> no sé hacer ninguna de las 2.

¿Sabéis como podría solucionarlo?

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('cuadrados.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

canny = cv2.Canny(gray, 10, 150)
canny = cv2.dilate(canny, None, iterations=1)
canny = cv2.erode(canny, None, iterations=1)
canny = cv2.GaussianBlur(canny, (1,1), 0)

cnts,_ = cv2.findContours(canny, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

figure = {
    2: "line",
    3: "triangle",
    4: "rectangle",
    5: "pentagon",
    6: "hexagon",
    7: "heptagon"
}

# 'f' lo utilizo para saber cuantos lados ha detectado en aquellos polígonos que detecte más de 7
f=0

for c in cnts:
    epsilon = 0.01 * cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, epsilon, True)
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)

    if len(approx) in figure.keys():
        cv2.putText(image, figure[len(approx)], (x, y - 5), 1, 1.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    else:
        cv2.putText(image, str(f), (x, y - 5), 1, 1.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        print(f, ":", len(approx))
        f+=1
    cv2.drawContours(image, [approx], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow("image", image)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

## Imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No puedo reproducir el código ahora, pero tu epsilon es bastante baja (distancia máxima entre el contorno y la aproximación),  ¿has probado con algo en torno al 10% (`0.1 * cv2.arcLength`)? debería corregir al menos algunos de los casos.

Comment: Muchas gracias @FJSevilla, solucionado. Puedes publicar respuesta si quieres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A la hora de aproximar el contorno, tal como comentas, cosas como el ruido en la imagen, imperfecciones en las formas o simplemente el aliasing afectaran a la precisión del ajuste. Puedes intentar corregir estos problemas dado el caso, pero lo primero y más simple a probar es ajustar la tolerancia.

La función [`approxPolyDP`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga0012a5fdaea70b8a9970165d98722b4c) se implementa usando el [algoritmo de Ramer–Douglas–Peucker](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker) dónde *épsilon* denota la distancia máxima tolerada entre la curva original y su aproximación. En el caso de `approxPolyDP` el argumento `epsilon` denota la distancia máxima entre el contorno de la figura y el contorno aproximado, especifica por tanto la precisión. Si la distancia entre un "lado" de la figura al contorno aproximado es mayor que `épsilon` se descarta esa aproximación y se busca otra, si es menor ese "lado" se ignora y la aproximación se considera válida.

Un ejemplo (para nada preparado ni exagerado...):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En tu caso la tolerancia es muy baja, de solo el 1% del contorno (`arch length`), si la subes al 10%:

```
epsilon = 0.1 * cv2.arcLength(c, True)
```

corregirás el problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Nota:** Por si alguien se lo pregunta, el gran rectángulo verde inferior y los dos azules superiores no se detectan como tales por estar "pegados" a los bordes de la imagen.

No existe un valor "correcto" para *épsilon*, variará para cada caso y aplicación particular, en general es un parámetro que hay que ajustar de forma empírica o incluso dinámicamente en tiempo de ejecución en algunos casos.